# How to implement FCM with heroku backend app

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to send FCM push notification from a chrome extension. I've implemented at the moment the `chrome.gcm` api that is the easiest way to get FCM working and I'm able to get a registration token and get incoming notifications sended from the FCM console.

Since I need to use the server key into the POST requests to the fcm endpoint to send messages, I want to setup a simple heroku backend as an alternative to cloud functions.

at the moment I have this POST request in my client code, but I'm using it only for dev the chrome extension

```js
            axios.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', {
                to: 'APA91bELmJY8xTU...',
                notification: {
                    title: 'Test notification',
                    body: 'Some cool text payload'
                }
            }, {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'key=AAAA6C5BuxA:...',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then( (res) => {
                console.log(res)
            })
```

Into the production version I want to move this code to the heroku app.

Is possible to use `firebase-functions` npm package on heroku or I need to setup an express app with an endpoint?

I've found [this buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/googlecloudplatform/buildpacks) but I'm not sure if it will give me the ability to write my heroku nodejs code like a cloud function

```js
functions.https.onRequest( (req, res) => { ... })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is possible to use firebase-functions npm package on heroku?

The `firebase-functions` package is the glue between Google Cloud Functions and your (server-side) Firebase code. There is no simple way to use it on a Heroku instance.

Setting up a custom Express endpoint sounds like the more idiomatic approach here.